# How to set select value in select2 plugin - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use this code for insert data to `select` element with `select2` plugin:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ws.asmx/GetEvrakGrup",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (dc, status) {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(dc.d);
        $("#selectId").select2({
            data: jsonData
        });

    },
    error: function () { alert("This is an Error");}
});
```

After I want to set a value in this select but its not working:

```
$("#selectId").val(81);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#selectId").val(81).trigger('change');
```

Instead of

```
$("#selectId").val(81);
```

Comment: No worries Huseyin, hope your project will be a huge success.

Answer (score 6):

```js
$("#MyDropdownList").select2("trigger", "select", {
                        data: { id: theID, text: theText }
                    });
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

try below code:

```
var $example = $("#selectId").select2();
$example.val(81).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Hi @Prashant Patill, i take same result.Its not working

Comment: oh! have you checked select2 examples?
please look in to it https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: [{ "id": 1, "text": "100-VOLKAN DİLLİOĞLU" }, { "id": 18, "text": "100-BÜLENT HASIRCI" }, { "id": 34, "text": "100-SEMRA TAŞDEMİR" }, { "id": 37, "text": "100-GÜRKAN ÖZTÜRK" }, { "id": 22, "text": "100-HASAN ABLAK" }, { "id": 24, "text": "100-SEVİL AŞKIN" }, { "id": 49, "text": "100-SELMA KABAKÇI" }, { "id": 59, "text": "100-MÜJDAT DÜŞMEZ" }, { "id": 81, "text": "100-HANDAN CANAN AYYILMAZ" }]